# Make an API call from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api

I'm attempting to make a call to an API, which takes requests in the form of Mongodb's '.find' method.

Using postman I can make the following call and I get the correct response.
[http://asterank.com/api/asterank?query={"full_name": {"$eq" : "(2004 EU22)"}}&limit=5](http://asterank.com/api/asterank?query=%7B%22full_name%22:%20%7B%22$eq%22%20:%20%22(2004%20EU22)%22%7D%7D&limit=5)

But, when I try to make the same call in JavaScript, my entire web application just shows a blank webpage. So is the following way of utilizing a mongodb call wrong?

```
var example = "0";

function getAsterank(){
//ARRAY OF NEO NAMES
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", 'http://asterank.com/api/asterank?query={"full_name": {"$eq" : "(2004 EU22)"}}&limit=5', false);
    xhr.send(null)
    responseData = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    xhr.abort();

    example = responseData;
}
```

If I make this same exact JS call using a different api such as the following, it works just fine. I use sublime text so I don't think I can debug it to see whats actually happening.
v

```
ar MeMe = "0";

function getAsterank(){
//ARRAY OF NEO NAMES
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", 'https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed/today?detailed=true&api_key=NnRe38qGPTpKPtsenpkqROMTtXvkWnVNyql9lmnP', false);
    xhr.send(null)
    responseData = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    xhr.abort();

    MeMe = responseData;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide API reference for first one?

Answer (score 0):

if jquery is an option this might be a solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".submitBottom").click( function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://asterank.com/api/asterank?query={"full_name":{"$eq":"(2004 EU22)"}}&limit=5',
            encode: true,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("success", data)
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see any mention of `encode: true` in the ajax docs. Also, you should explain why you think this is a solution.